# Outdated flag reasons

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, flagging

The flag reasons are outdated: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts.   It still has "too localised" and others. Shouldn't it be updated?

Edit: just a bump to the front page, as this is still outdated. Should this be taken up to Meta Stack Overflow?